Find a way of coloring such that each vertex of $K_{m+n-1}$ has $m-1$ red edges and $n-1$ blue edges
Sometimes we can color the edges of $K_{m+n-1}$ such that each vertex can have $n-1$ red edges and $m-1$ blue edges, but sometimes we can not (for example, $m=n=2$).
Prove if at least one of $m, n$ is odd, then we have the above coloring.
I tried to use induction.
Base case $m=1$, for any $n$, trivially we have the coloring.
Now suppose $m=2k-1$, for any $n$,we have the coloring. We need to show $m=2k+1$, now we have two additional vertices, so color one of the edges red and one of the edges blue (try to balance the red and blue edges from the two vertices). Since $m$ is odd, I can end up coloring the edge between the two new vertices with the needed color.
I have the coloring.
Am I right in doing this way?

What have you tried? There's a pretty natural construction to test. Hint: Reflection. $\quad$ How do you exploit the fact that $m-1$ is even? Why does it not work if $m-1$ is odd?

What do you mean by reflection?

(To be clear, I'm not continuing from your approach, but just creating the construction for an odd $m$.) How do you exploit the fact that $m-1$ is even? Well, it can be split into 2 parts evenly. What is a natural thing to do with 2 parts, perhaps can we place them on 2 sides?

I tried to follow your point by putting two $K_{m-1/2}$ on 2 sides while keeping $K_n$ in the middle, but no matter how I tried to color the graph, I still do not get the ideal results.

WLOG $m-1$ is even.
Place the $m+n-1$ vertices around the circle. Color the edge according to the following Rule:

For each vertex, let the edge to the preceding and following $\frac{m-1}{2}$ vertices be red, and the rest be blue.

Show that

This yields a valid coloring. In other words, for the edge $uv$, ensure the coloring given by the Rule on $u$ and the coloring given by the Rule on $v$ are the exact same.
For each vertex, it is connected to $m-1$ red edges and $n-1$ blue edges.

Hence this construction satisfies the requirements.

Note

This coloring might not have been a "natural construction" as I thought it would be. EG In this question (which is a close duplicate), it took 6 months before that solution was added in.

Though I hope that you would agree this is "obvious/natural" in hindsight.


Bonus: Show that if both $m-1, n-1$ is odd, then such a coloring does not exist.

Thus a coloring exists iff $mn$ is even.




For the bonus question, I think the reason is we can not distribute m-1 points symmetrically on the two sides of a vertex $v$. Then for example, we place 3 on the left and 4 on the right. Then if $u$ is the fourth from the left, $(u,v)$ will get red by the rule of $v$, but get bule by the rule of $u$.

@Andrew_Ren For the bonus, yes the rule doesn't work because we don't have a valid coloring (which is why point 1 is so important to show). $\quad$ Moreover, the way it is phrased, I'm asking you to demonstrate that no such coloring exists (and not just the coloring obtained from this rule).

Take the red-edge induced graph of $G$. 1. it must has all the vertices (m+n-1 which is odd) because any vertex has red edge (in fact $m-1$ red edges). 2.  Any vertex has odd degree $m-1$. Contradiction.

Yup, and this gives us a complete classification for what $m, n$ values work.

To prove the construction above is valid, can we do as follows? Orient clockwise the circle, for a vertex $v$, denote the following $v_1, \cdots, v_{\frac{m-1}{2}}$, the proceeding $v_{-1}, \cdots, v_{-\frac{m-1}{2}}$. Now $(v,u)$ is red iff $u=v_i$ iff $u=v_j$ iff $(u,v)$ is red.
